# Using Twitter4j and Geolocation to find users who posted a tweet in the area, but how to get the users ID?

Tags: java, api, twitter, geolocation

```
Query query = new Query("MDX").geoCode(new GeoLocation(51.589344, -0.228242), 5, "km"); 
query.count(11); //You can also set the number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100
QueryResult result;
        result = twitter.search(query);


//Set the language of the tweets that we want
query.setLang("en");//Language codes listed here;
```

I'm trying to use `tweet.getUser().getId` but having problems completing it

Comment: You said you have tried to use `tweet.getUser().getId`. Where is the code?

Comment: I know I have to use this code but have trouble constructing it

Comment: print the variable result, we need to see it to understand